# Why Docker doesn't throw error if I delete my SQLite database using bind volume mount?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sqlite

So I have [a project using Next.js + SQLite + Litestream (Database Backups on Cloudflare R2) + Docker](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/easypanel-nextjs-sqlite/) & I tried to perform database delete on `/data` folder on container (`./data/` on disk) to see if database recovers properly.

The data does recover properly.

But I'm curious that when I delete the database using `rm -rf data/` in command line.

It doesn't throw any error in my application & it keeps working.

[image: sample db on localhost]

Even after I deleted the `data/` folder, `Add One`, `Get All`, `Delete All` keep working. Idk where the `data/` gets stored.

Fwiw, I use <strike>anonymous volumes</strike> bind mount in Docker Compose.

#### docker-compose.yml

```yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    image: easypanel-nextjs:0.0.1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nextjs-sqlite
    env_file:
      - .env.production
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
```

Now what happens is the data only works until I stop the server using `docker-compose down` & then when I restart again, it goes back to the previous state (before I perform `rm -rf data`)

In short,

1. I do `docker-compose up`
2. Add, Get, Delete work fine. Let's say `data = { name: 'abby' }`
3. Litestream makes backup of `data/` on every insert or delete.
4. I delete `data/` folder.
5. I can still access my web app successfully even though `data/` folder which contains my `*.sqlite` doesn't exist. It should crash here but doesn't.
6. I can still Add, Get, Delete. Let's say I do `data = { name: 'abby', name: 'nia' }`
7. Now when I stop using `docker-compose down` & run it back up again using `docker-compose up`, I only get `data = { name = 'abby' }`. `nia` is deleted because I deleted `data/` folder before adding `nia`.

How's that happening? Is it using anonymous volume? I can't get into anonymous folder no matter how I try. I also don't know how to download `*.sqlite` inside anonymous folder if I somehow access it so I can view its contents.

Is this behavior normal? I would love to solve it. Like if database doesn't exist, it should just crash.

Full reproduction can be found at https://github.com/deadcoder0904/easypanel-nextjs-sqlite/

Comment: If a file is removed while it is open by a program then it is not actually removed, only the reference to it is removed from the containing directory. The file itself still exists and can be accessed by the program until it closes the file. Once the file is closed, it is finally removed.

Comment: @AlexD now it really makes sense. thank you alex. if you add it as an answer, i'll upvote it. i have another question: does docker + sqlite wal mode not work for the same reason. it also resulted in data loss. i've provided reproduction steps on https://github.com/deadcoder0904/easypanel-nextjs-sqlite/ under heading `SQLite WAL Mode Caveats`. ironically, it works when used with litestream.io because of litestream's wal mode. what are your thoughts on that? is the answer same as this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote from [unlink(2) man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html)

> unlink() deletes a name from the filesystem.  If that name was
> the last link to a file and no processes have the file open, the
> file is deleted and the space it was using is made available for
> reuse.

> If the name was the last link to a file but any processes still       have the file open, the file will remain in existence until the last file descriptor referring to it is closed

Answer (score 1):

As [Alex](https://serverfault.com/users/23022/alexd) said in the comments, it doesn't delete the file.

It just deletes the reference to it. Like Pointers in C.

So the file is still alive & all database operations are still working.

Once the file is closed, it is actually removed.

This is very confusing if you are using Windows (host) & Linux (container) in Docker.

Because you can see in Windows, the `./data` directory is deleted. It is also deleted in Linux if you check `/data` using `ls /data`.

I did that & found this:

```bash
$ docker exec -it nextjs-sqlite sh
/app $ ls /data
ls: /data: No such file or directory
```

But I guess it isn't truly deleted. Maybe this is how [Linux works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31099347/6141587). Maybe [Windows too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3202329/6141587).

Comment: Clearly it is platform dependent. Windows has an exclusive mutex access that can prevent Windows Explorer from updating the modified date of the file. A key takeaway is don't expect the semantics to be the same on one platform as another.